# Python - checking a list for possible patterns and if the list meets a specific condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a novice making a small game for learning purposes.
The game rolls dice based on the inputs of the user.

The part I'm having trouble with is I want to check for patterns in the list "rolls"

patterns include:

1. all dice are the same value and the # of sides >=4 EXAMPLE [1, 1, 1, 1] < values are the same, atleast 4 sides. If true then mutiply user_Score by 10
2. at least half of the dice are >= "average_sum" with the condition that the list must have >= 5 dice

   - EXAMPLE if avg_sum = 2   and rolls = [2,3,4,1,1,] If true then mutiply user_Score by 5
3. all of the dice are different values with the conditions # of dice > 4 and # of sides > # of dice
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
4. No pattern matches. -> Multiply user_Score by 1

```
number_dice = int( input( "How many dice are you using? Must be between 3-6 inclusive" ) )
faces = int( input( "how many sides are on your die? enter a number between 2-20 inclusive: "))

# Set range for number of dice
#generate a random number between 1 and faces
#Add dice_roll to the list

rolls = []
for die in range(number_dice):
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, faces)
    rolls.append(dice_roll)

#print the score from each dice rolled
print("You have rolled: " + str(rolls))

#calculate sum of score
sum = sum(rolls)

#calculate the average and round to the nearest integer
average_sum = round(sum / number_dice)

print("These die sum to: " + str(sum) + " and have an average value of: " + str(average_sum))


#Calculate the max possible score
max_score = (number_dice * faces)

#calculate the users score
user_score = float( sum / max_score )

print("your max possible score is " + str(max_score))

print("your score is " + str(user_score))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#now calculate the bonus factor
#Check if the list "rolls" contains the same value for each index

if rolls == {repeatingvalues???} and rolls {number_dice>=4}:
    user_Score * 10
elif rolls == {half of dice > average} and {number_dice >=5}:
user_Score * 5
elif rolls == {all dice have different values} and { number_dice > 4}{faces> number_dice}:
    user_score * 8
else:
    user_score * 1
```

Not sure how to make this statement search the list for a pattern^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to check for a repeating pattern that returns `True` or `False`

```
def has_repeats(my_list):
    first = my_list[0]
    for item in mylist:
        if not item == first:
            return False
    return True
```

And then define a function to check for a no duplicates that returns `True` or `False`

```
def all_different(my_list):
    # Remove duplicates from list
    my_list2 = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
    return len(my_list) == len(my_list2)
```

And finally define a function to check if half the dice are greater than the average:

```
def half_greater_than_averge(my_list, average):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for item in my_list:
        if item > average:
            a += 1
        else:
            b += 1
    return a > b
```

So you final checks will be:

```
if has_repeats(rolls) and number_dice >= 4:
    user_Score * 10
elif half_greater_than_averge(rolls, average_sum) and number_dice >= 5:
user_Score * 5
elif all_different(rolls) and number_dice > 4 and faces > number_dice:
    user_score * 8
else:
    user_score * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, faster and more 'Pythonic' way of doing it.

```
if all(x == rolls[0] for x in rolls):
    print("Same")

elif len(rolls) == len(set(rolls)):
    print("Unique")

elif number_dice/2 <= [x > avg_sum for x in rolls].count(True): 
    print("Half")

else:
    print("No match")
```

The 'and' conditions are missing. Please feel free to add them.

**Bonus**

```
from random import randint
faces = int(input('Number of faces:'))
number_dice = int(input('Number of dice:'))
rolls = [randint(1, faces) for _ in range(number_dice)]
```

Feel free to explore

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out my solution where add # ------ SOLUTION STARTS HERE -------
2. I helped refactor your code too. You shouldn't be using `sum` as a variable name (or identifier) in your code cos it's a reserved python keyword. So I changed it to `my_sum`. Check if it still works as desired.

`import math # import math at the top`

```
import random


number_dice = int( input( "How many dice are you using? Must be between 3-6 inclusive" ) )
faces = int( input( "how many sides are on your die? enter a number between 2-20 inclusive: "))

# Set range for number of dice
#generate a random number between 1 and faces
#Add dice_roll to the list

for die in range(number_dice):
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, faces)
    rolls.append(dice_roll)

#print the score from each dice rolled
print("You have rolled: " + str(rolls))

#calculate sum of score
my_sum = sum(rolls)

#calculate the average and round to the nearest integer
average_sum = round(my_sum / number_dice)

print("These die sum to: " + str(my_sum) + " and have an average value of: " + str(average_sum))

#Calculate the max possible score
max_score = (number_dice * faces)

#calculate the users score
user_score = float( my_sum / max_score )

print("your max possible score is " + str(max_score))

# ------ SOLUTION STARTS HERE------

rolls.sort() 
rolls.reverse()
for item in rolls:
    if (rolls.count(item) >= 4) and (number_dice >= 4):
        user_score *= 10
        break
    elif (rolls[math.ceil(len(rolls)/2) -1] >= average_sum ) and (number_dice >= 5):
        user_score *= 5
        break
    elif (sorted(rolls)==sorted(list(set(rolls))))and (number_dice > 4) and (faces > number_dice):
        user_score *= 8
        break
    else:
        user_score *= 1

# ------ SOLUTION ENDS HERE------

print("your score is " + str(user_score))
```